# Visual Studio 2019 not showing filter controls at top of code view

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In previous versions the code view always display 2 filter controls on the top bar just beneath the tabs. Using these controls you could filter by item and its properties/event, etc. Mine don't display how do i turn them on?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Tools -> Options menu, then navigate to Text Editor > C# (or whatever language you're using) > General and be sure to check the "Navigation bar" entry under Settings